# Why explicitly require application controller in Rails engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I am building a Rails engine and I noticed that if I generate a controller like so `rails g controller test` it gives me the following output:

```
require_dependency "my_app/application_controller"

module MyApp
 class TestController < ApplicationController
 end
end
```

Why is it necessary to require the engine's application controller, the nesting under `module MyApp` should already disambiguate the ApplicationControlller from the main app's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I did some digging through the rails source and found the commit who introduced this feature (sha: 7c95be54)

> Fix generators to help with ambiguous `ApplicationController` issue
>
> In development mode, dependencies are loaded dynamically at runtime,
>   using `const_missing`. Because of that, when one of the constants is
>   already loaded and `const_missing` is not triggered, user can end up
>   with unexpected results.
>
> Given such file in an Engine:

```
module Blog
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   end
end
```

> If you load it first, before loading any application files, it will
>   correctly load `Blog::ApplicationController`, because second line will
>   hit `const_missing`. However if you load `ApplicationController` first,
>   the constant will be loaded already, `const_missing` hook will not be
>   fired and in result `PostsController` will inherit from
>   `ApplicationController` instead of `Blog::ApplicationController`.
>
> Since it can't be fixed in `AS::Dependencies`, the easiest fix is to
>   just explicitly load application controller.

So as one could have guessed, this comes down to an autoloading issue! So remember kids, always make explicit what you import when dealing with potentially ambiguous code.
What is really disconcerting is that the namespacing introduced by engines, really doesn't provide too much isolation, imagine you reference some other non-rails class in your engine and the including main app happens to have a constant of the same name, the same issue would apply.

Comment: There is actually no module isolation. The only isolation it provides is in routes where you don't have to explicitly specify the namespace, other than that, it's simply an extension of your main app. Rails just adds the engine to your load path.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to this post for the [same issue within Component-based Rails apps](https://github.com/shageman/component-based-rails-applications-book/issues/7). Leaving my thoughts here for future reference...

Mountable engines come with a namespace, which allows for another way of solving this issue: *Always reference every class explicitly with its namespace*, i.e., `Blog::ApplicationController`.

In your case, the following code would not have the problems described (no need for the explicit `require`).

```
module Blog
  class PostsController < Blog::ApplicationController
  end
end
```

Of course, you could still run into the issue that two namespace/class combinations show up in the app, but this will be much more rare and easier to spot...